# Run a Query from a different query results

Tags: ms-access

I'm fairly new to access so learning the basics of the different functions. How do you run a query based on a different query's results?

Ex: What I'm trying to do is find all units in a table that don't have a FldNo. "9". Do I need to run a query that says, show me all units with a FldNo. "9" and then a second query saying, show me all units not on the first query...or is there a better way to pull this info? Thanks

Comment: Why can't you just ask directly for `WHERE FldNo <> "9"` ?

Comment: That doesn't give me what I'm looking for unfortunately. Each unit in the table should have a FldNo value 1-80. I specifically need to see all units that don't have a FldNo value 9

Comment: I'm lost then.  If the issue is that you want to also see rows where FldNo is Null, you can add that condition ... `SELECT * FROM YourTableNameHere WHERE FldNo <> "9" OR FldNo Is Null;`  If that's still not what you want, please show us a brief data sample and the results you want to see from a query based on those data.

Comment: On query2, what criteria would I need to say to find all units from the units table not included on query 1

Comment: Have you tried using a join query? Check it out and if you don't get it comment back.